# Almost Everywhere Conservative Vector Field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

$$F(x,y) = \left \langle\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}, \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},0 \right \rangle $$

Is a famous example of a vector field whose curl is zero away from the origin but does not have potential function associated with it. However, can a potential function be defined almost everywhere that works? I think this function can be increasing as it goes - say starting at zero on the x-axis. When it comes back, it will be at a higher value. But since I have specified that it be defined a.e., the value along the x-axis won't matter. I don't know how to explicitly write this function though.

Comment: If $V$ is the potential function, the question is what does the equality $\nabla V=F$ mean? In the classical sense, you need a differentiable $V$, which implies that it is continuous. The other usual sense is the distribution sense, but you must specify on which domain and it won't exist in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(0,0)\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, we ignore the last $0$ component of $F$ and just consider it as a vector field in $\mathbb R^2$.

A potential function can always be defined on a simply connected open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2\backslash \{0\}$ by picking any $x_0\in \Omega$ and write
$$
\phi(x) =\int_{x_0}^x -F(y)dy.
$$
The integral is, of course, path-independent, by Green's formula, as long as the path lie in $\Omega.$

An explicit expression can be obtained by evaluation this integral explicitly, which isn't that difficult. To make sure that almost every point in $\mathbb R^2$ lies in $\Omega,$ just take $\Omega = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \Gamma,$ where $\Gamma$ is any simple curve connecting $0$ to $\infty.$

Of course, all things above are in classical sense. If we work in distributional sense things can be a little more interesting.